# Dart Plugin from JetBrains does not re-analyzes files modified outside of JetBrains IDE

Tags: dart, jetbrains-ide

Dart Plugin from JetBrains does not re-analyzes files modified outside of JetBrains IDE.
Is there any possibility to force this plugin to analyze files that have not been modified manually, but which have been modified through the file system?

The following solutions does not works:
1) File -> Synchronize
2) File -> Invalidate Caches

That is, the IDE itself works fine, but the Dart plugin doesn’t react to these operations at all (does not respond to changes in the file).

Only IDE restart helps.

[image]

The upper part of the image shows exactly how errors are highlighted incorrectly after making changes (the backlight does not fall on the text).

The lower part of the image shows what comes after the restart IDE (the backlight falls on the text).

Comment: This is not a known issue and I failed to reproduce it so far. Details matter. First of all: Dart SDK version, IDE logs (Help -> Show Logs). Project configuration is important. Is it a standard single-folder project with pubspec.yaml in the project root? Is it stored on a local hard drive? Are there symlinks? You may submit an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (Subsystem: Dart) with all the details. Though, most likely, it's not a Dart plugin issue but some misconfiguration.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this by hand.  But "not in manual mode" it works like this. The parser generator in the "bin" directory generates a parser file in the "bin" directory. The plugin recognizes changes after the first generation. But after each subsequent generation, this plugin incorrectly displays the location of errors in the generated file.
That is, the plugin incorrectly points to other lines of the source text containing errors in the source code.The script (dart file) parser generator is run in the IDE debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is: yes, to force reanalyze Dart files click 'Restart Dart Analysis Server' button in the Dart Analysis tool window.

But this answer doesn't solve the problem. Error highlighting should be up-to-date without any extra actions. I suggest filing an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB (Subsystem: Dart) and provide details: Dart SDK version, IDE log files (Help -> Show Log) and steps to reproduce (ideally attach a sample project).

Comment: Thank you. Restart Dart Analysis Server. This is enough for me. That is what I needed. I did not know how to do it.